# Store user who uploaded file with Paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, paperclip, multifile-uploader

I am building a photo gallery app in Rails (following [this guide](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails)). I would like to expand on the app this guide builds by adding Devise user authentication and storing who uploads each photo. I have got Devise running nicely but I'm not sure what the best way to keep track of who uploads what. 
This is what I'm thinking:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  ...
end
```

```rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs to :user
  ...
end
```

```rb
class AddUserToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :photos, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

The above (as I understand it) would store the uploader in each photo record and as an added bonus, allow us to run `@user.photos` to see all of a users photos regardless of gallery.

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, this will do.

Comment: Yes but you should setup a foreign key and index on `photos.user_id`. If you run the migration generator as `rails g migration AddUserToPhotos user:belongs_to` it will create them for you.